# What is Rusty Ryan is referring to in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-thirteen

In the movie Oceans Thirteen, after the drill hit the bank's hotel building for the third time, the drill does not stop at once; it goes on for several seconds and the building vibrates. Then Rusty asks others (maybe he asks himself),

> **Do you think Roman would.... [pause]  Nah.....**

Then we see Roman Nagal drinking from a soda/beer can.

What I want to know is, what exactly Rusty was referring to in his dialogue above? I can't think of anything that fit into the plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual line was

> Do you think Nagel was...nah

It's in reference to a deleted scene where Roman Nagel talks about the possibility that their earthquake scheme might cause an actual earthquake.

He would have said, "Do you think Nagel was right about causing a real earthquake?"

See the [deleted scenes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09nDSTJgsI0) at around 3:05 mark and watch as he is leaving the room.